IAM Policy and Force Detach Policy in Terraform defined for AWS logGroup and DynamoDB
IAM Role and Force detach Policy is defined for log group and DynamoDB table but in code Force Detach Policy is not accepting policy defined instead expecting boolean value (true/false)
**Note: Terraform resource for AWS_IAM_ROLE....**
resource "aws_iam_role" "get_applicant_group_file_iam_role_lambda_execution" {
  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Effect = "Allow"
        Principal = {
          Service = [
            "lambda.amazonaws.com"
          ]
        }
        Action = [
          "sts:AssumeRole"
        ]
      }
    ]
  })
  force_detach_policies = [
    {
      PolicyName = join("-", ["backend", "dev", "lambda"])
      PolicyDocument = {
        Version = "2012-10-17"
        Statement = [
**Note: Policy define for Create and Put Logs**
          {
            Effect = "Allow"
            Action = [
              "logs:CreateLogStream",
              "logs:CreateLogGroup",
              "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ]
            Resource = [
              "arn:${data.aws_partition.current.partition}:logs:${data.aws_region.current.name}:${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:log-group:/aws/lambda/backend-dev-getApplicantGroupFile:*:*"
            ]
          },
**Note: Policy define for DynamoDB tables.**
          {
            Effect = "Allow"
            Action = [
              "dynamodb:DescribeTable",
              "dynamodb:Query",
              "dynamodb:GetItem",
              "dynamodb:PutItem",
              "dynamodb:UpdateItem"
            ]
            Resource = [
              "arn:aws:dynamodb:${data.aws_region.current.name}:${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:table/job-app-backend-dev",
              "arn:aws:dynamodb:${data.aws_region.current.name}:${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:table/job-app-backend-dev/index/GSI1"
            ]
          },
          {
            Effect = "Allow"
            Action = [
              "s3:GetObject"
            ]
            Resource = "arn:aws:s3:::jobapp.pk-dev-us-east-1-media/*"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
  path = "/"
  name = join("-", ["backend", "dev", "getApplicantGroupFile", data.aws_region.current.name, "lambdaRole"])
  managed_policy_arns = [
  ]

I have define boolean expression but that is not the solution i am looking for.

Check the first note in the resource documentation: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_role


If policies are attached to the role via the aws_iam_policy_attachment resource and you are modifying the role name or path, the force_detach_policies argument must be set to true and applied before attempting the operation otherwise you will encounter a DeleteConflict error. The aws_iam_role_policy_attachment resource (recommended) does not have this requirement.

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_role
